# необходимо ли брать в скобки часть условия, содержащую тернарный оператор?

Tags: java

```
boolean canDelegate = AFSession.get()
                               .currentUser()
                               .getSubstituteOf()
                               .contains(participant) 
                                && (reply == null ? false : reply.getPublishTime() != null);
```

Comment: Попробуй убери) скорее всего не нужны

Comment: а не будет ли он без скобок рассматривать проверяемое условие тернарного оператора полностью от присваивания переменной до "?" ? типа
boolean canDelegate = (AFSession.get().currentUser().getSubstituteOf().contains(participant) && reply==null)
?
(false)
:
(reply.getPublishTime()!=null);

Comment: Да, скобки нужны

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Таблица приоритетов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) явно указывает, что приоритет оператора `==` выше тернарного оператора. Также это можно подтвердить опытным путем:

```
System.out.println(1 == 2 > 1 ? 2 : 1);
```

Получаем ошибку несовместимых типов.

То есть сначала выполнился оператор `>` в выражении `2 > 1`

После чего выполнился оператор `==` в выражении `1 == true`, что и вызвало ошибку.

То есть ответ: да, скобки нужны.